# how to make a container take remaining height of screen

Tags: flutter

I want to make the container of "send a message" container take the remaining height of screen.
I tried using wrapping the container with expanded and flexible but it's not working.

Image of the page

[image]

Complete page code:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:chatbot/const/constants.dart';
import 'package:chatbot/widgets/chat_message.dart';
import 'package:chatbot/widgets/dot_animation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:chat_gpt_sdk/chat_gpt_sdk.dart';
import 'package:flutter_chat_bubble/chat_bubble.dart';

import '../api/api_key.dart';
import '../widgets/Button.dart';

class ImageGeneratorScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const ImageGeneratorScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<ImageGeneratorScreen> createState() => _ImageGeneratorScreenState();
}

class _ImageGeneratorScreenState extends State<ImageGeneratorScreen> {
  final TextEditingController controller = new TextEditingController();
  OpenAI? openAI;
  StreamSubscription? subscription;
  bool isTyping = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    openAI = OpenAI.instance.build(token: openAIApiKey);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    subscription?.cancel();
  }

  void receiveMessage() async {
    final request = ChatCompleteText(
        messages: [Messages(role: Role.user, content: controller.text)],
        maxToken: 200,
        model: GptTurbo0301ChatModel());

    final response = await openAI?.onChatCompletion(request: request);
    ChatMessage receivedMessage = ChatMessage(
      text: response!.choices[0].message!.content,
      isMe: false,
    );
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
          child: Text(
            'Image Generator',
            style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 24, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, letterSpacing: 0.6),
          ),
        ),
        elevation: 2,
        centerTitle: true,
        leading: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
          child: GestureDetector(
            child: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            SafeArea(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 10),
                    child: Container(
                      child: ClipRRect(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                        child: Image.asset('assets/images/default_image.jpg'),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 10,
                      ),
                      Button(
                        text: 'Copy Prompt',
                        icon: Icons.copy,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 5,
                      ),
                      Button(
                        text: 'Download HD',
                        icon: Icons.download,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 10,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  BottomMessageScreen(),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget BottomMessageScreen() {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0).copyWith(bottom: 5),
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20).copyWith(
            bottomLeft: Radius.circular(30),
            bottomRight: Radius.circular(30),
          ),
          color: DarkModeColors.textFieldColor,
        ),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.0),
              child: TextField(
                keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                maxLines: null,
                textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.sentences,
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                controller: controller,
                onSubmitted: (value) {},
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: "Send a message",
                  hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                  border: InputBorder.none,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10).copyWith(bottom: 10),
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              child: Text(
                'Generate',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 23,fontWeight: FontWeight.w900),

              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget TypingIndicator() {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0),
          child: CircleAvatar(
            child: Icon(Icons.abc),
            radius: 15,
          ),
        ),
        ChatBubble(
          clipper: ChatBubbleClipper5(type: BubbleType.receiverBubble),
          alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10, left: 10),
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(0).copyWith(bottom: 5),
          backGroundColor: Colors.grey.shade800,
          child: Container(
            height: 40,
            width: 60,
            child: DotAnimation(),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Code of bottom part:

```
Widget BottomMessageScreen() {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0).copyWith(bottom: 5),
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20).copyWith(
            bottomLeft: Radius.circular(30),
            bottomRight: Radius.circular(30),
          ),
          color: DarkModeColors.textFieldColor,
        ),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.0),
              child: TextField(
                keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                maxLines: null,
                textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.sentences,
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                controller: controller,
                onSubmitted: (value) {},
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: "Send a message",
                  hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                  border: InputBorder.none,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10).copyWith(bottom: 10),
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              child: Text(
                'Generate',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 23,fontWeight: FontWeight.w900),

              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

I tried using wrapping the container with expanded and flexible but it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

You are having `body: SingleChildScrollView`, adding Expanded on body will cause constraints issue (infinite height). I can't see the use case of this. You can remove it if I understand it correctly.

Use `LayoutBuilder` on top to get the size of view.  Also removing SingleChildScrollView will allow expanded as child.

```dart
body: SafeArea(
  child: LayoutBuilder(
    builder: (context, constraints) => Column(
      children: [
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 10),
          child: Container(
            height: constraints.maxWidth/2, // though can be use flex
            color: Colors.red,
            // child: ClipRRect(
            //   borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
            //   child: Image.asset('assets/images/default_image.jpg'),
            // ),
          ),
        ),
        Row(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              width: 10,
            ),
            // Button(
            //   text: 'Copy Prompt',
            //   icon: Icons.copy,
            // ),
            SizedBox(
              width: 5,
            ),
            // Button(
            //   text: 'Download HD',
            //   icon: Icons.download,
            // ),
            SizedBox(
              width: 10,
            ),
          ],
        ),
        Expanded(child: BottomMessageScreen()),
      ],
    ),
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a `SizedBox.expand`, which ensures that the parent space is completely consumed, and the child is told to be as big as it wants inside that.

```
return SizedBox.expand(child: YourWidget());
```

I've been known to insert these as the `body` of a Scaffold to make sure my layout takes the entire screen.